# Label on button got blurry after click and animated back in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem with label on button in WPF. After I click the button, label get blurry and than it get clear, but it looks like animation and last about 2 seconds.

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding DefaultCommand}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="../Images/add_all.png" />
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2">All</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I set style only for width, height and margin for targettype = button.

`RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="ClearTypeHint"` doesn't help.

[image: Left - directly after click, right - few seconds later]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing is just the standard behaviour of a WPF button on Windows 7 with no custom style applied. When a standard button is clicked upon, an animation starts, changing the button background from gray to blue and back to gray, over around 2 seconds. When you select another control, the animation stops.

Not sure why you are seeing blurry label text though.

Is hardware rendering disabled on your PC maybe?

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I have noticed the same issue as well running Visual studio 2012 in Windows 8 x64. Was not able to fix and just used a work around. It occurred while running a RenderTransform on the button during a storyboard animation.